# Org-mode capture without location and date

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I would like to customize my org-mode capture so that the output in my `notes.org` file will be in the simpler form:

`* TODO WhatIwanttodo`

without anything else. At the moment I get something like this:

```
* TODO Make a new post in the blog explaining how u can put TODO in org mode using the android app by IFTTT  [2015-03-14 Sat 09:21 [[file:~/Dropbox/org/dailywork.org::*ES][TODOES]]
```

Comment: You are somehow using a complex capture template. Please add to your post the value of the customization variable `org-capture-templates`.

Comment: One way is `M-x org-customize`, find _Org capture_, and inside that group, find `org-capture-templates`.

Comment: Is this good? http://pastebin.com/49PfeSi2 Here is my .emacs part about capture: http://pastebin.com/bA5YEYCR . Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two variations:

The first one adds a todo to a file under header TODO-HEADER. The second simply appends it to the end of file.

```
 (setq org-capture-templates
      '(
        ("s" "Simple" entry (file+headline "my-org-todo-file" "TODO-HEADER")
         "* TODO %?")
        ("x" "Very Simple" entry (file "my-org-todo-file")
         "* TODO %?")
         ))
```

Template can be very powerful. I recommend you read

http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture-templates.html#Capture-templates